# GCP Health Checks with SSL enabled

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, health-check

I kind of new on Kubernetes stuff and I'm trying to improve one current system we have here.
The Application is developed using Spring Boot and until now it was using HTTP (Port 8080) without any encryption. The system requirement is to enable e2e-encryption for all Data In-Transit. So here is the problem.

Currently, we have GCE Ingress with TLS enabled using Let's Encrypt to provide the Certificates on Cluster entrance. This is working fine. Our Ingress has some Path Rules to redirect the traffic to the correct microservice and those microservices are not using TLS on the communication.

I managed to create a Self-Signed certificate and embedded it inside the WAR and this is working on the Local machine just fine (using certificate validation disabled). When I deploy this on GKE, the GCP Health Check and Kubernetes Probes are not working at all (I can't see any communication attempt on the Application logs).

When I try to configure the Backend and Health Check on GCP changing both to HTTPS, they don't show any error, but after some time they quietly switch back to HTTP.

Here are my YAML files:

1. admin-service.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: admin-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: admin
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 8443
    name: https
    protocol: TCP
```

2. admin-deployment.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "admin"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "admin"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "admin"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "admin"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "backend-admin"
        image: "gcr.io/my-project/backend-admin:X.Y.Z-SNAPSHOT"
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health/liveness
            port: 8443
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 8
          periodSeconds: 30
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health/readiness
            port: 8443
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 8
          periodSeconds: 30
        env:
        - name: "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID"
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID"
              name: "service-config"
---
apiVersion: "autoscaling/v2beta1"
kind: "HorizontalPodAutoscaler"
metadata:
  name: "admin-etu-vk1a"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "admin"
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: "Deployment"
    name: "admin"
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
  - type: "Resource"
    resource:
      name: "cpu"
      targetAverageUtilization: 80
```

3. ingress.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-ingress-addr
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my-domain.com
    secretName: mydomain-com-tls
  rules:
    - host: my-domain.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /admin/v1/*
          backend:
            serviceName: admin-service
            servicePort: 443
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: XXX.YYY.WWW.ZZZ
```

Reading [this document from GCP](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#backend-encryption) I understood that Loadbalancer it's compatible with Self-signed certificates.

I would appreciate any insight or new directions you guys can provide.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:** I've added here the ingress YAML file which may help to a better understanding of the issue.

**EDIT 2:** I've updated the deployment YAML with the solution I found for *liveness* and *readiness* probes (`scheme`).

**EDIT 3:** I've found the solution for GCP Health Checks using annotation on Services declaration. I will put all the details on the response to my own question.

Comment: Did you try locally on minikube or a similar solution to be sure that your health check is valid on 8443 and locally before deploying in the cloud?

Comment: When I disable SSL on my service (but keeping port 8443) everything is working just fine. GCP Health Check works and Kubernetes Probes are working and showing on the logs.

Comment: Are you sure about your SSL configuration? There is only error trace on the probe, not on the SSL engine?

Comment: Running the spring boot locally with TLS enabled everything works just fine. When I deploy it on GCP, the application logs do not show any error, just de regular log messages. But you give another idea, I will deploy the Spring Boot app with DEBUG log message enable, maybe this way I find something new. @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for your help and feel free to add more comments.

Comment: I'm intriguing about your issue. Don't hesitate to update your post with the solution!!! Or the new clues that you can found.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution to part of the issue. The part regarding "livenessProbe" and "readinessProbe". Their definition on YAML file was missing "scheme: HTTPS". 
Now my spring boot application is responding 200 OK to those GET. 

The other part is regarding GCP Health Check. I'm getting SSL Exception when requested (I found this enabling DEBUG logs on Spring).

Comment: Have you checked the created healthcheck in `GCP -> Compute Engine -> Healthchecks`?  Have you changed the protocol used there?

Comment: Hi @DawidKruk. Yes, I did try that. When I change the Health Check to HTTPS it stays that way for some time and switches back to HTTP and I don't have any clue why it's doing this. I mean, I don't see any error on the logs, it just goes back to the previous configuration.

Comment: Which actions did you manually perform that would get reversed eventually? How exactly have you configured your E2E? Please provide your `Ingress` definition. Also you can try to create a pod inside of the cluster and "ping" your `spring-boot-pod`  to check if communication is happening correctly.

Comment: Hi @DawidKruk, I did an update on my post adding the Ingress definition, please take a look. Regarding the changes in GCP Backend Service and Health Checks, I used the GCP Panel changing their respective protocols to HTTPS. `GCP -> Network Service -> Backends` and then `GCP -> Compute Engine -> Health checks`

Comment: Hi again @DawidKruk, I did run a ubuntu pod inside my cluster and used it to curl my service. It seems to be working just fine. `curl https://cluster_ip:443` does complain about the self-signed certificate and `curl https://cluster_ip:443 -k` does show my 200 OK response with **healthy service** body

Comment: I finally find how to make it work. I will update my question and then write a proper answer. Thanks, guys for helping me with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I found on how to fix the issue.

After reading a lot of documentation related to Kubernetes and GCP I found a document on GCP explaining to use annotations on Service declaration. Take a look at lines 7-8.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: admin-service
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"https":"HTTPS"}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: iteam-admin
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 8443
    name: https
    protocol: TCP
```

This will hint GCP to create the ***backend-service*** and ***health-check*** using HTTPS and everything will work as expected.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress-xlb#https_tls_between_load_balancer_and_your_application